# Snackbar onclick do ondismiss action

Tags: android, android-activity, android-snackbar

Hello my App have a scanner and if the code don't correspond to anything, it show a snackbar asking the user if they want to add the scanned product to the database with a click on the snackbar button, and going to the main activity if the user dismiss the LENGTH_INDEFINITE snackbar, but when I click, it also do the ondismiss message:

```
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Aucun produit correspondant", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)  //Si il n'y a pas de produit correspondant, affiche un snackbar qui propose de l'ajouter a la base de donnée
        .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                Log.i("Snack", "dismiss");
                startActivity(new Intent(ScannerResultActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            }
        }).setAction("Ajouter", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ScannerResultActivity.this, ScannerResultAddProductActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ean", getIntent().getStringExtra("ean"));
                Log.i("Snack", "onclick");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When clicking the action of a `Snackbar` the `Snackbar`'s `onDismiss()` method is called (because the `Snackbar` is being dismissed by default when clicking on its action), so your code will first call the `onClick()` method and then call the `onDismiss()` method.

Comment: Is there any method to do want I want or should i use an AlertDialog ?

Comment: Depends on whether you want one or more actions to show. Snackbars can only hold one action. If you want more then one action you should indeed consider using something like an AlertDialog.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use the Snackbar widget for this?
You would do this much easily with an `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Do you want to add this to the database?")
   .setCancelable(true)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //do things
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```